# Returning ITaskItem[] array from a function / method, in the most direct manner

Tags: c#, msbuild

Is there a way to transfer the items, which are read from the file, **directly** without adding them to a `List` first and then converting the list `.ToArray` and casting it into `ITaskItem[]` ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CS_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static ITaskItem[] ReadItems(string SrcPath)
        {
            List<ITaskItem> Items = new List<ITaskItem>();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(SrcPath);
            foreach (string line in lines)  {
                Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"(?>^[^=\S\n]*(?<var>[^=\n\s]+)[^=\S\n]*=[^\S\n]*)(?<val>[^\n]*?)[^\S]*$");
                if (m.Success)  {
                    ITaskItem it = new TaskItem(m.Groups["var"].Value);
                    it.SetMetadata("val", m.Groups["val"].Value);
                    Items.Add(it);
                }
            }

            return Items.ToArray(); 
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ITaskItem[] Items = ReadItems(@"C:\vars.txt");
        
            foreach (var it in Items ) {
                Console.WriteLine(it.ItemSpec + " == " + it.GetMetadata("val"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the `C:\vars.txt` file are below:

> aaa=111
> bbb=
> ccc=333

P.S.
The function `ReadItems()` must return the type `ITaskItem[]` because Microsoft requires that type for returning `MsBuild Items` from [`inline tasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-inline-task?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I do not understand the requirement that the `ReadItems` method must return an array " because MsBuild requires it for inline tasks". What do you mean by that?

Comment: I have added a blue link at the bottom of my question, which documents returning `MsBuild Items` from `inline tasks`.

Comment: Well, if you have to return an array, then I don't see any improvement here. The point of returning an array means that all elements must be included before the result can be passed back to the caller. Also the cast `(ITaskItem[])` after `.ToArray()` is unneeded.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know that the cast does not have to be explicit.  I just included that cast so it is very obvious that the program must do the extra work of that casting there.

Comment: The cast is going to be removed by the compiler, so really, there is no point in typing it. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAFgG5NMEBmfJXAYVwG9NcX8qFDcBZACgEpGzVsIBuEAE64ANlADOAF1wBeXDACmAd1wAZOfIA8BbAD5+pDMOFGA2gF1cE8RACey3Dxu2+MhQDoAKgD2AILiTs5mQpa4AGaB4moQAMYAFu5iklDyamC4sA5hLnxRlkwW0dEEAJw8WTl8xKwlwgC+JW0YLUA===

Comment: Really?, ...it will not have to convert the structure of that array behind the scenes ?

Comment: That's what `ToArray()` does. Hover over the method call and you can see the return type is `ITaskItem[]`, not an object array or something else. There's no point in casting because it's already the type you want.

Comment: Done. The cast is gone...

Comment: If you are worried about performance, stop worrying. Compared to reading a text file and executing regular expressions on the file content, the overhead of creating a list and turning it into an array can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example 'vars.txt' only has lines that will match. A version of the file with non-matching lines would be:

```
# vars.txt
aaa=111
bbb=

ccc=333
=222
```

Because the file is read completely into `lines` and because the `Regex` is matching lines, the number of items that can be found cannot exceed the length of `lines`. You could define an `ITaskItem` array of `lines.Length`.

The code might be changed as follows:

```
        static ITaskItem[] ReadItems(string SrcPath)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(SrcPath);
            ITaskItem[] Items = new ITaskItem[lines.Length];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"(?>^[^=\S\n]*(?<var>[^=\n\s]+)[^=\S\n]*=[^\S\n]*)(?<val>[^\n]*?)[^\S]*$");
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    ITaskItem it = new TaskItem(m.Groups["var"].Value);
                    it.SetMetadata("val", m.Groups["val"].Value);
                    Items[index] = it;
                    index++;
                }
            }

            if (index < Items.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref Items, index);
            }

            return Items;
        }
```

You might wonder about the `Array.Resize(ref Items, index)`. When there are lines that fail to match the `Regex`, there will be null `ITaskItem` objects in the array and an MSBuild task should not be returning null `ITaskItem` objects.

As asked, this approach avoids creating a `List<ITaskItem>` and avoids calling `.ToArray()` to convert the list to an array, but `.ToArray()` and `Array.Resize()` are both creating new arrays and are both O(`n`) where `n` is the number of `TaskItem` objects.

As noted in the comments, the file read and the RE matching are the big expenses in the function. Comparatively, using `new List<ITaskItem>()` versus `new ITaskItem[lines.Length]` is inconsequential.

**One note about inline tasks:**

It's painful to write and maintain inline C# code within MSBuild. There is no IntelliSense and when the inline code fails some of the MSBuild messages are cryptic. But the [`Code` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2022#code-element) can be used with a file that is a complete class. You can create a file that is a task class.

e.g. A 'MyTask.cs' file (not a complete example):

```
    ...

    public class MyTask : Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            ...

            return !Log.HasLoggedErrors;
        }

        ...
    }
```

This source file can be part of a project and you can edit and build the task as C# code. Alongside the source file, you can create a 'MyTask.targets' file which would contain the `UsingTask` element for the task. The `Code` element within `UsingTask` would specify `Class` as the `Type`.

e.g.

```
      <Code Type="Class" Source="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyTask.cs" />
```

The 'MyTask.targets' file can be imported where needed. If the code is all in one code tree/repo just reference the 'MyTask.targets' file wherever it is. If the code is in different trees/repos always 'ship' the 'MyTask.targets' and 'MyTask.cs' files together.